# $2 {\mathbb Z}$ is flat

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove that $2 {\mathbb Z}$ is flat. Note that this is not injective and not projective.

Proof: For injective $ 
{\mathbb Z}$-module homomorphism $L \rightarrow_f M$, consider $$ 2{\mathbb Z}\otimes L\rightarrow_{1\otimes f } 2{\mathbb Z}\otimes M $$

If $1\otimes f (2n\otimes l)=2n\otimes f(l)=0 $, so $f(nl)=0$ Hence $nl =0$ So $2n\otimes l=0$

Proof is right ?

Comment: The module $2\mathbb Z$ is free (basis is $\{2\}$) and thus projective, thus flat.

Comment: $2{\mathbb Z}$ is not direct summand of ${\mathbb Z}$ So not projective ${\mathbb Z}$-module ?

Comment: An abelian group is torsion-free if and only if it is flat over $\mathbb{Z}$. Now $2\mathbb{Z}$ is torsion-free.

Comment: $2\mathbb{Z}$ **is** a direct summand of a free module - of $2\mathbb{Z}$ itself.

Comment: $2\mathbf{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}$ as $\mathbf{Z}$-modules.

Comment: I see : $R={\mathbb Z}$-module $F=2{\mathbb Z}$ is free since $F$ has a subset $A =\{ 2\}$ and any element $x$ in F has unique $r\in R$ s.t. $x=r2$